# my Controller actions not hit after deploy mvc3 application on IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I develop accounting application in mvc3.it is run correctly in visual studio 2010.After develop some portion i want to check it by deplploy on IIS7.5. it deploy correctly but it does not hit my controller actions which i use to get data from database through AJAX and jquery. below is my controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AutocompleteSuggestions(string term)
{

        var namelist = objSvc.GetAutoCompData(term);


        return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

below is my javascript function which use this controller function and get the results from database

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $("#AcCode").autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteSuggestions", "Home")', //"/Home/AutocompleteSuggestions",
                 type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                       return {
                            label: item.code, value: item.desc                            
                        }
                        }))
                }
            })
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
             event.preventDefault();
             if (ui.item) {
             $("#Descrip").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#AcCode").val(ui.item.label);

            }

        }

    });
});



    });
```

it works correctly when run in visual studio 2010 and give me exact results.but after deploy it in iis7.5 
it will give error NetworkError: 404 Not Found
    "zulfiqar/CBS/JV/@Url.Action(%22GetVNO%22,%20%22JV%22)"
here Zulfiqar is my system name and cbs is application name.

I also add deployable assemblies at publish time.please any one tell me why this give error on IIS.

NOTE:it give the following error in firebug html panel.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /CBS/JV/@Url.Action("GetVNO", "JV")

Comment: Here problem is not about stringify of data.data is sent but controller action is not found and hit here.Please give some suggession about my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by adding error message in controller like this.

```
 [HttpPost]
public JsonResult AutocompleteSuggestions(string term)
{
try
{
var namelist = objSvc.GetAutoCompData(term);
return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 return Json(new { ok = false, message = ex.Message });
}
}
```

it will return me the exact error in the firebug.Actually it give error in url parameter of autocomplete function." url: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteSuggestions", "Home")', " some illegal characters was passed so the controller was not hit. So i change it and now my application work correctly in IIS.